# Unable to login to paypal using paypal payment button - localhost

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I'm trying to make online payment using paypal button. I make the button using some instruction from paypal for developers. The paypal payment button shows fine on the page, but when I want to pay (test) it open me a popup, where I need to login with paypal account. I tried to login with another paypal account, because the money should come to my paypal account, but every time it shows me a error message "Check your email address and password and try again", email address and password are correct because I can login to paypal on another tab.

Image for popup where I need to login to paypal account and the error message

[image]

Here is code I got from paypal developers:

```js
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
// Render the PayPal button
paypal.Button.render({
// Set your environment
env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

// Specify the style of the button
style: {
  layout: 'vertical',  // horizontal | vertical
  size:   'medium',    // medium | large | responsive
  shape:  'rect',      // pill | rect
  color:  'gold'       // gold | blue | silver | white | black
},

// Specify allowed and disallowed funding sources
//
// Options:
// - paypal.FUNDING.CARD
// - paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
// - paypal.FUNDING.ELV
funding: {
  allowed: [
    paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
    paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
  ],
  disallowed: []
},

// Enable Pay Now checkout flow (optional)
commit: true,

// PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
// Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
client: {
  sandbox: 'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
  production: '<insert production client id>'
},

payment: function (data, actions) {
    totalPrice = $('.price').val()
    totalPrice = parseFloat(totalPrice)
    
  return actions.payment.create({
    payment: {
      transactions: [
        {
          amount: {
            total: '1.0' ,
            currency: 'USD'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
},

onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.execute()
    .then(function () {
      window.alert('Payment Complete!');
    });
}
}, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

```html
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in with a Sandbox account?  Since you're working in the sandbox (according to your screenshot) you need to make sure you're logging in with a [Sandbox buyer account](https://www.angelleye.com/create-paypal-sandbox-account/) for testing.

Comment: I will try to use sandbox account to test the button, thanks anyway